# Java String appending with comma as a separator

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I have a requirement where I need to append multiple values from multiple web service calls into one final string with comma as a separator.

Some of the values might be null, in that case I need to check for not null and then append it as empty string.
If there is no value for one of the string, comma should not get appended.

Please help me resolving this. here is the code what I did.

```
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (usersList.totalCount != 0 && usersList.totalCount >= 1) {
                logger.info("usersList.totalCount ----->"
                        + usersList.totalCount);
                for (KalturaUser user : usersList.objects) {
                    if (user.id != null) {
                        sb.append(userId);
                    }
                    if (user.firstName != null) {
                        sb.append(",").append(userFirstName);
                    }
                    if (user.lastName != null) {
                        sb.append(",").append(user.lastName);
                    }
                    if (user.email != null) {
                        sb.append(",").append(user.email);
                    }
                    if (user.roleNames != null) {
                        sb.append(",").append(user.roleNames);
                    }
                    if (user.partnerData != null) {
                        sb.append(",").append(user.partnerData);
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(sb);
            }
```

Thanks,
Raji

Comment: You already did that. What is your problem with current code now ?

Comment: I am not getting what's happening: output is:null,null,
null,null,
null,null,admin,james.smith@kaltura.com,,pw=f865b53623b121fd34ee5426c792e5c33af8c227,
null,null,Bandel,,,pw=7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b,123456
null,null,Farnsworth,pacoh@mx1.ibm.com,,pw=9bc34549d565d9505b287de0cd20ac77be1d3f2c,
null,null,Peleg,,,pw=64c1a55c1af56bc31d1e1480390737678577ef10,
null,null,Colodny,david.colodny@kaltura.com,,pw=e0c93ecb0f02f2ca30af9f5edea91c1a328705a8,
null,null,

Comment: Well, in `if (user.id != null) { sb.append(userId);` you are testing `user.id` but appending `userId`.

Comment: @Suresh - If the value is not there, then its coming as null for some strings and empty for some strings. so the final output is like the above.

Comment: @Pshemo - Yes. I modified the code and its fine now. Thanks.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add description of the problem there. You should also remove sensitive data like e-mail addresses if they are real (replace them with some `foo@bar.com`, `john@doe.net` if you wish). I would also remove hashed passwords.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public static String asString(Object value) {
    return value == null ? "" : value.toString();
}

for (KalturaUser user : usersList.objects) {
    sb.append(asString(user.id));
    sb.append(",").append(asString(user.firstName));
    sb.append(",").append(asString(user.lastName));
    sb.append(",").append(asString(user.email));
    sb.append(",").append(asString(user.roleNames));
    sb.append(",").append(asString(user.partnerData));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your tests like

```
if (user.id != null) {
    sb.append(userId);
}
```

you are checking `user.id` but appending `userId`. These are two different variables.

You should probably change it into

```
if (user.id != null) {
    sb.append(user.id); //instead of sb.append(userId);
}
```

Comment: Yes ... I did a mistake. Thanks. Its fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your problem is, but if you are looking for a better or different approach, I found that it is best to append to a List<String> and then use [StringUtils.join](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String)) to produce the final string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class from a google library called Joiner.

```
String concatenedString = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls().join(itemToAdd);
```

You can find this class on google-collections-1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that. It's based on Java8 streams, but here you don't need to do the non-null check on every property(`.filter` does this for you). I assumed that `users.object` is an array list, if it's not you might need to convert it into stream in other way

```
if (userList.totalCount > 0) {
    logger.info("usersList.totalCount ----->" + usersList.totalCount);

    String result = userList
                    .objects
                    .stream()
                    .map(user -> {
                        return Stream.of(user.firstName, user.id, user.lastName, user.email, user.roleNames, user.partnerData) //get the properties you need into the stream
                                        .filter(property -> property != null) // filter out null properties
                                        .collect(Collector.joining(",")); //join them by comma
                    })
                    .collect(Collector.joining(",")); //join user strings with comma

    System.out.println(result);
}
```